# JavaScript: Speed up my script. Best Practice?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm creating a custom formula in Google Sheets App Script. The formula (script) works as intended. It's kinda slow though. Is there a way to make it operate faster? Like something where it will try each different variable in an array? Or a best practice? Thanks in advance!

```
    function tag3(cell){
  var BAK = "BAK"
  var FRS = "FRS"
  var LAJ = "LAJ"
  var LMC = "LMC"
  var MAL = "MAL"
  var PPH = "PPH"
  var SBD = "SBD"
  var VVC = "VVC"
  var WCL = "WCL"
  var BEL = "BEL"
  var GAL = "GAL"
  var KCK = "KCK"
  var PAS = "PAS"
  var PHX = "PHX"
  var TUL = "TUL"
  var RIC = "RIC"
  var SDG = "SDG"
  var STO = "STO"
  var WAT = "WAT"  
  
  if(cell.indexOf(BAK)>-1) {return BAK}
  if(cell.indexOf(FRS)>-1) {return FRS}
  if(cell.indexOf(LAJ)>-1) {return LAJ}
  if(cell.indexOf(LMC)>-1) {return LMC}
  if(cell.indexOf(MAL)>-1) {return MAL}
  if(cell.indexOf(PPH)>-1) {return PPH}
  if(cell.indexOf(SBD)>-1) {return SBD}
  if(cell.indexOf(VVC)>-1) {return VVC}
  if(cell.indexOf(WCL)>-1) {return WCL}
  if(cell.indexOf(BEL)>-1) {return BEL}
  if(cell.indexOf(GAL)>-1) {return GAL}
  if(cell.indexOf(KCK)>-1) {return KCK}
  if(cell.indexOf(PAS)>-1) {return PHX}
  if(cell.indexOf(TUL)>-1) {return TUL}
  if(cell.indexOf(RIC)>-1) {return RIC}
  if(cell.indexOf(SDG)>-1) {return SDG}
  if(cell.indexOf(STO)>-1) {return STO}
  if(cell.indexOf(WAT)>-1) {return WAT}
  
  else {return cell}
  
    
    }
```

Alternative:

I tried what the users below suggested and it didn't seem to work for me. I decided to completely not make my own custom function in Google App Scripts and just created a script that runs when I select a certain cell.

This is the code. It runs in about 2-3 secs (much much much faster than original).
It may not be pretty, but I'm happy with the results and the speed.

It searches each cell value in a range for a specific string. It then "extracts" that 3 character string and also tells me what track that string is assigned to.

Example:

Cell Value: BAK 313 KIN 317 VRN
Script will find "BAK" is within cell and it will then paste that value with its assigned track, in this case 102.

So my new result is "BAK  102"
I then use the Google Sheets function RIGHT and search for the assigned track, in this case "102"

I can then use that 102 to look up a track.

```
function onSelectionChange(e){
  
  var selection = e.range;
  
  if (selection.getA1Notation() === 'A1') {
    
    var tagCol = mainSheet.getRange("N4:N250");
    var data = mainSheet.getRange('OL4:OL250').getDisplayValues();
    
    
  
  
  data.forEach(function(e, i){ 
    var range = []
    if (e[0].indexOf("BAK")>-1) {range.push("N" + (i + 4))
    mainSheet.getRangeList(range).setValue("BAK  102") }});
  
  data.forEach(function(e,i){
    var range =[]
    if (e[0].indexOf("FRS")>-1) {range.push("N" + (i + 4))
    mainSheet.getRangeList(range).setValue("FRS  104") }});
  
  data.forEach(function(e,i){
    var range =[]
    if (e[0].indexOf("LAJ")>-1) {range.push("N" + (i + 4))
    mainSheet.getRangeList(range).setValue("LAJ  113") }});
  
  data.forEach(function(e,i){
    var range =[]
    if (e[0].indexOf("LMC")>-1) {range.push("N" + (i + 4))
    mainSheet.getRangeList(range).setValue("LMC  114") }});
  
  data.forEach(function(e,i){
    var range =[]
    if (e[0].indexOf("MAL")>-1) {range.push("N" + (i + 4))
    mainSheet.getRangeList(range).setValue("MAL  115") }});
  
  data.forEach(function(e,i){
    var range =[]
    if (e[0].indexOf("PPH")>-1) {range.push("N" + (i + 4))
    mainSheet.getRangeList(range).setValue("PPH  105") }});
  
  data.forEach(function(e,i){
    var range =[]
    if (e[0].indexOf("SBD")>-1) {range.push("N" + (i + 4))
    mainSheet.getRangeList(range).setValue("SBD  115") }});
  
  data.forEach(function(e,i){
    var range =[]
    if (e[0].indexOf("VVC")>-1) {range.push("N" + (i + 4))
    mainSheet.getRangeList(range).setValue("VVC  109") }});
  
  data.forEach(function(e,i){
    var range =[]
    if (e[0].indexOf("WCL")>-1) {range.push("N" + (i + 4))
    mainSheet.getRangeList(range).setValue("WCL  112") }});
  
  data.forEach(function(e,i){
    var range =[]
    if (e[0].indexOf("BEL")>-1) {range.push("N" + (i + 4))
    mainSheet.getRangeList(range).setValue("BEL  108") }});
  
  data.forEach(function(e,i){
    var range =[]
    if (e[0].indexOf("GAL")>-1) {range.push("N" + (i + 4))
    mainSheet.getRangeList(range).setValue("GAL  110") }});
  
  data.forEach(function(e,i){
    var range =[]
    if (e[0].indexOf("KCK")>-1) {range.push("N" + (i + 4))
    mainSheet.getRangeList(range).setValue("KCK  111") }});
  
  data.forEach(function(e,i){
    var range =[]
    if (e[0].indexOf("PAS")>-1) {range.push("N" + (i + 4))
    mainSheet.getRangeList(range).setValue("PAS  107") }});
  
  data.forEach(function(e,i){
    var range =[]
    if (e[0].indexOf("TUL")>-1) {range.push("N" + (i + 4))
    mainSheet.getRangeList(range).setValue("TUL  111") }});
  
  data.forEach(function(e,i){
    var range =[]
    if (e[0].indexOf("RIC")>-1) {range.push("N" + (i + 4))
    mainSheet.getRangeList(range).setValue("RIC  106") }});
  
  data.forEach(function(e,i){
    var range =[]
    if (e[0].indexOf("SDG")>-1) {range.push("N" + (i + 4))
    mainSheet.getRangeList(range).setValue("SDG  101") }});
  
  data.forEach(function(e,i){
    var range =[]
    if (e[0].indexOf("STO")>-1) {range.push("N" + (i + 4))
    mainSheet.getRangeList(range).setValue("STO  106") }});
  
  data.forEach(function(e,i){
    var range =[]
    if (e[0].indexOf("WAT")>-1) {range.push("N" + (i + 4))
    mainSheet.getRangeList(range).setValue("WAT  103") }});
    
    
  }
  
}
```

Comment: I would probably try using a regular expression that matched for everything in one pass (like a big `(WCL|BEL|GAL)` etc. How much text is in the cells?

Comment: @xdhmoore There's not much text in the cells. The minimum string will be 3 characters. The max will be about 23, but that's very rare. Most cells will be an average of 6 ish.

Comment: Another thought: It may be that that cell.indexOf() call is more expensive than it looks. You might try pulling the text out into a string first and then doing all your searches on the string

Comment: I can't find an indexOf() method in the google sheets docs, which makes me wonder if your `cell` object is already a string. In which case, this function doesn't really throw up any performance red flags to me.I would wonder what is calling the tag3 function and if the slowness might be outside.

Comment: So the slowness isn't when I use a single cell. But when I drag this formula down a Column (which is how this formula will be used all the time) (in this case 150 rows), it takes about 5 mins for the spreadsheet to populate everything

Comment: The code doesn't look slow.  I think there may be overhead in a custom script. Try replacing the whole function with just `return cell`.  How fast is that?

Comment: So, when you drag the formula does it call this function once with `cell` set to all the selected cells, or does it call the function once for each cell, passing in each selected cell one by one? What is the type of the `cell` input variable? An array or some object or a string?

Comment: My guess: `cell` is an `Array` of `Range` objects that are being casted to strings when you call `indexOf` on the Array. I wonder if you might speed things up by converting all the Range objects in `cell` to strings up front and using an Array of strings to do your indexOfs. My only other thought is you could use a prefix tree but that's getting a little crazy.

Comment: @xdhmoore When I drag this formula, it calls the function once for each cell. So instead of gathering a single cell, I could gather a range (array) and return it in array in each cell. so that it only calls function once? If so, I wouldn't know how to do that. But I'm eager to learn!

Comment: @user2740650 I replaced the entire script with return cell. When I drag it down in a column (with 250 lines), it is still very very slow.

Comment: @Kyler that's as I thought.  So optimizing the script isn't going to help, but maybe if there are alternate approaches like xdhrmoore suggested, that may help.  See "Optimization" at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions where it says your approach will be slow :-)

Comment: @user2740650 I think you're right. I think it's a limitation of Google Sheets not JS. I was able to recode my script and get results I'm happy with where it is MUCH faster. about 1-2 secs for the same range of 250 rows.

Comment: @Kyler that's great   You should post an answer to your own question.  It gives you points and helps out the next person to encounter this.

Comment: @user2740650 Okay I will. Thank you for letting me know. I wasn't sure if I should, but I'll  do that. Thank you much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looping through cell on every single if statement.
You have 20 items, and each `.indexOf()` is looping through cell array (or string) from start to finish or until the item is found. This makes your function `O(20N)`.
Change the cell to a Set or an object so that the lookup is instant. Rather than looping through the cell, loop through the search terms you've created and check if it exists in the cell set.

```js
function tag3(cell) {
  const items = [
    'BAK',
    'FRS',
    'LAJ',
    'LMC',
    'MAL',
    'PPH',
    'SBD',
    'VVC',
    'WCL',
    'BEL',
    'GAL',
    'KCK',
    'PAS',
    'PHX',
    'TUL',
    'RIC',
    'SDG',
    'STO',
    'WAT',
  ];
  const cellSet = new Set(cell); 

// if cell is a string, split cell into an array 
// of 3 letter strings

  for (let item of items) {
    if (cellSet.has(item)) {
      return item;
    }
  }
  return cell
}
```

In case you're not familiar with the `Set` datatype, here's a reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Comment: I think you meant to use a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop...

Comment: @itsoyu Thanks for the reply. It seems like you're on the right path. I copied your code and plugged it in and but I get an error "Missing ; after for-loop initializer." . I've tried adding a ; in places and it doesn't clear it.
Does App Script not allow "of" to work?
Also I noticed in your code it says "items" instead of "item". Is that a typo?

Comment: @Kyler it should be `let item of items`. If that doesn't work it's probably because ES6 is not available for whatever reason on your codebase. If that's the case, you can use the traditional for loop: `for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) { 
var item = items[i] 
}` and don't forget to use `var` instead of `const` or `let`.

Comment: @itsoyu Apparently I had to click a click something to activate Chrome V8 runtimes, which didn't give me that error anymore. However, it still didn't work for me.

I then tried the for loop and that didn't seem to do anything for me either.

Comment: @Kyler is your cell argument an array or a string? Try checking if `cellSet` is correctly defined. What's the output you're getting?

Comment: Here are a few examples of what the cells contain.

[BAR VVC 0041 COF], 
[BAK 313 KIN 317 VRN], 
[WCL WC LOH45 CSI] 

In the actual formula on the sheet, I'm getting an error. It doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Kyler looks like your example is an array of length 1 with the string "BAR VVC 0041 COF". You'll need to split this string into an array.